How to specify the nodejs snapshot directory when I use the --heapsnapshot-near-heap-limit option
The node service is subject to occasional oom. He runs on Kubernetes, and every time an oom occurs it causes the container to restart, and the snapshot printed using heapsnapshot-near-heap-limit is destroyed.
You need to specify a directory to be mounted separately in Kubernetes to retain the snapshots.
And I didn't find the option to specify a directory in the nodejs documentation.
What should I do?
There is another strange phenomenon, the container's memory limit is set to 3000Mi, and Nodejs' --max-old-space-size is set to 4096, but when GCC occurs, the memory footprint is only 1200M, which is very puzzling.
129:0×5651d4fcba401 105786239 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1200.5 (1382.2）-= 1200.5 (1367.7) MB, 1432.5 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.101, current mu = 0.093) last resort GC in old space requested
129:0×5651d4fcba401 105787806 ms:Mark-sweep ( reduce) 1200.5 （1339.7) ->1200.5 (1325.4) MB. 1567.4/0.0ms
averace E current m = oooo lastresort oi olo space recuestec

Snapshots can be kept when nodejs oom
Because the program oom is very occasional, even sometimes not appearing for half a month, don't want to use the scheme of timed sampling to produce snapshots.
